# Showing that $\sum_{A \in \mathcal{F}}m(A) \ge 2$.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $I = (a,b), a < b.$ Let $m(I)=b-a$ and $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of open intervals such that $[0,1] \cup [2,3] \subset \mathcal{F}  = \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{F}} A$. Show that $\sum_{A \in \mathcal{F}}m(A) \ge 2$.

I'm  not sure I understand the question here. $\mathcal{F}$ seems to be an open cover for $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ and I would need to use this to show that the sum is at least equal to $2$?

Comment: You could try a simpler problem first. Can you show that if $[0,1] \subset \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal F} A$ then $\sum_{A \in \mathcal F} m(A) \ge 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $[0,1]$ is compact, a finite number of the given intervals cover it. Order the finite subset as follows: let $A_1$ contain $1$, $A_2 = (a_2, b_2)$ have $b_2 > a_1$ and $a_2 < a_1$ (which must exist since the intervals cover $[0,1]$), etc. with each interval overlapping the last one as such, until you cover the closed interval with $n$ of them. With $A_k = (a_k, b_k)$ and the construction that $b_k > a_{k-1}$ (except for $b_1$ since there is no $a_0$), we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k - a_k) > b_1 - a_1 + \sum_{k=2}^n (a_{k-1} - a_k) = b_1 - 1 + \left( (1 - a_1) + \sum_{k=2}^n (a_{k-1} - a_k) \right) \geq b_1 - 1 + 1 > 1$$
The same argument works for $[2,3]$.